# when using the wrap widget, How to can you replace the spacing or runspacing with a widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to put a dot between the labels, but only only between each item in each "row". There will be 8 dots total. each line shouldn't start or end with a dot. Any thoughts on how to do this?

[image: example of what I have]

Edit:
I want to give a list of widgets as a parameter. I do not know the height or width of the widgets that will be passed in. Creating this with a row is tricky, because I have to have some kind of logic that determines if there will be enough space for the widget before going to the next row.

Comment: How you are generating the rows?  can you include your widget? and I think it will be easy to archive   using Row or GridView in this case?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am using the wrap widget
(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)  the children is 10 text widgets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.